# What is the use of garbage collector methods in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

System.gc() or Runtime.gc() if you call there is no guarantee that there will be a garbage collection. Its up to the JVM to perform a GC. Then what is the point in having such methods?

Comment: It's like when your wife tells you to throw out the garbage. You might throw the garbage without her telling you. You might or might not throw the garbage even after she tells you. She tells you anyway. So what's the point of her telling you? You can look at it as a reminder to throw out the garbage.

Comment: The methods are very old, and Java has a pretty decent record of backwards compatibility. Even though they're not very useful methods anymore, there's not a lot of advantage in removing them either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc for `System.gc()` and `Runtime.gc()` is alluding to the fact that it is possible to configure a JVM to ignore calls to those methods; e.g. using the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` JVM option.

However, they are not configured that way by default (at least in current versions of Oracle and OpenJDK Java).  So, the calls will do something by default.

Having said that, in most situations it is a bad idea to call the garbage collector directly.  They few cases where it is reasonable are mostly covered by the following:

- if you are trying to investigate or test behavior of GC sensitive code; e.g. finalizers
- if you are trying to avoid a GC pause at an inconvenient point, by running the GC at a point where the user won't notice.

---

> I don't understand what is wrong with giving a guaranteed GC when I request `System.gc()`?

When you are able to invoke the garbage collector via a `gc()` call, it *typically* does a full collection.  That is expensive, especially when the amount of non-garbage data is large<sup>1</sup>.  Unfortunately, a lot of Java programmers don't realize this.  So, (as I understand it) the primary reason for the JVM option  to ignore explicit `gc()` calls is to mitigate the potentially catastrophic performance effect of programmers *abusing* the method.

If you *do* want your `System.gc()` calls to trigger a GC, the best advice is to make sure that you don't include `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` in your JVM options.

Read the Oracle manual entry for the `java` command for more information.

<sup>1 - Most of the runtime cost of a garbage collection is in tracing and copying the graph of objects that are still reachable.  If you tell the collector to run before it needs to, you reduce its efficiency.  By contrast, the JVM itself knows when the heap is full, or close enough that a collection is warranted.  Indeed, it can optimize for two different requirements; maximizing throughput, or minimizing GC pause times.</sup>

Comment: I see your point, but i dont understand what is wrong with giving a guaranteed GC when I request System.gc() ?  That way i can better design things and expect it to work the way i want...May be it will come with a price (performance) but if it can guarantee to to run at the time i requested it, I will be able to handle it better... ..I can run that GC at a point when user wont notice like you told

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java 7 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc())

> public static void gc()
>
> Runs the garbage collector.
>
> Calling the gc
>   method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward
>   recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently
>   occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method
>   call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space
>   from all discarded objects.
>
> The call System.gc() is effectively equivalent to the call:
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().gc()

So, essentially, it's a suggestion to the GC heuristics that right now is a good time to free some memory. For example, say you're writing a game where the framerate is locked to 60FPS. Each frame has a budget of 16.6 (repeating, of course ;)) milliseconds. Say your frame only takes 5ms to run. Usually, you would wait the remaining time with `Thread.sleep`. However, you could instead opt to call `System.gc()` first, to tell the VM "hey, I have some extra time -- feel free to clean up while I wait". Of course, you have no guarantee that the garbage collection will take less than the 11.6MS you have remaining! But if done carefully it can help your memory usage and prevent garbage collection from happening at a bad time. Similar principles apply to other kinds of applications -- basically, if you know that your application will have some downtime, you can let the VM know with `System.gc()` and hopefully prevent the GC from instead deciding to run in the middle of something important.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are right saying there is no guarantee that jvm will actually start gc right after your `System.gc()` call. However gc can take a note of your willing to make collection now and actually run it.

It depends from jvm, but as far as I know hotspot jvm actually runs gc after `System.gc()` or `Runtime.gc()`, at least most of the times.

So I would say that not having at least one way to suggest vm to run gc would have been a mistake. There can be different vm implementations, and what if there is a vm which wants to provide possibility to call gc with guarantee that it would actually run after such call, it wouldn't break specification and it might be usefull for some cases, and as I already mentioned hotspot vm most probably wouldn't ignore this call.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are provided if someone wants to take hold of garbage collection(which was valid for old JVMs) but its always wise to leave garbage part on JVM specially Modern JVM implementations have highly optimized garbage collectors. Our jobs has made easy by modren JVM implementations so we have to only focus on java code.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `gc()` calls should not be provided in the first place when there is no use case. I can think of at least one positive and two negative points of using explicit GC calls:

1. If you are building an application where you have little control of JVM options and want to achieve some God level tuning from within the code, you may use an explicit call. But rest assured, that this is not a magic call to get GC done in scenarios where you suddenly expect low load for a few minutes. You may need to put in a lot of effort to achieve that like estimating responsiveness of GC, amount of memory to be collected, etc.
2. `System.gc()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` may serve as a reminder or suggestion, but it is completely a prerogative of JVM to do so or not.  On the contrary, it might not do anything at all upon seeing such request. Reference: [Oracle Java](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6668279)
3. Having said that, it's usually avoided because GC is something which can be controlled and handled via external JVM options rather than from code itself. For example: [-XX:-DisableExplicitGC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#BehavioralOptions)